# Can I increase the efficiency of an exterior sump system by installing a check valve?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, exterior, sump-pump

My house only has an exterior sump system for a walkout basement in the central midwest. The sump seems to run through a cycle, pumping the water through the drain pipe (about 6" below the surface) which daylights at around 40 feet in a straight line to a free fall of around a foot. After the pump stops (and gurgles and bubbles) for a few seconds it starts again, and again, and again. 10 to 15 cycles every 10 to 20 minutes that I have counted, even after days without rain. This seems like a lot!

My questions are, would a check valve increase the efficiency of this sump pump? Where on the line would be the best place for the valve? Should I be concerned about the check valve freezing in Central Missouri? Should I try to regrade the drain line? Are there other options that I have not mentioned?

I have been told I need to install another sump in the basement, which is on my list, but that will have to wait until later.

ETA: [Pics of Sump and Drain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEHoR.jpg)

Comment: So your system has no check valve at present? Can you [edit] to add some pictures showing the setup? 12" in 40 feet is adequate slope if, in fact, it's sloped correctly the whole way (no dips and dives) as it's roughly 2" more than the minimum 10" required to have 1/4" per foot over 40 feet. But **I wonder if it's siphoning back from the line** to have that much restarting. What diameter is the pipe? Does it get larger where it turns to run downslope, or not? Possibly the one place I'd consider an AAV to be a good addition as a vacuum breaker at the corner.

Comment: I will edit with pics when I get home.

Comment: There is no check valve in the ~8' I have unearthed on the pump side.
I do not think there is much if any slope to the drain pipe. I will be digging more to better define the slope, I guess.
I had not considered a vacuum break, are these not integral to pumps?
The pipe is 1 1/4" for the length of the run.
Are you thinking a vacuum break at the corner where the drain leaves the pit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making some assumptions.

If the pipe is the same size, I have to think that your pump is siphoning back from the long drain line. So, options are to use

- a larger drain line (a bother, expensive)
- a plain vent (may need to be tall) or
- a mechanical vent or Air Admittance Valve, which is a one-way ingoing
  vent

So that only the water in the vertical pipe returns to the sump (without trapping any water higher to risk freezing.)

An alternate, easier, cheaper way to "make the drain pipe larger" is to leave the drain pipe alone and make the pipe from the pump to the corner smaller than it. The idea of that, either way it's done, is to make it hard for the pump to completely fill the drain line, so it self-vents from the end of the line.

[image: Sump options, drawn by me.]

Comment: I think the assumptions you made are correct. Is siphoning a common issue with sumps? The pit is in an ignorant spot, so the plain vent is out of the question. An AAV could do what is needed if siphoning is the issue. I will add one instead of the check valve in addition to redefining the slope of the drain. I will report back.

Comment: The "gurgle, bubble, restart many times" behavior is common in pumps with poorly sloped and unvented lines that contain enough water to refill the sump to the point that the pump starts again. Where freezing is NOT an issue a check valve may work to solve it, but where freezing is an issue (and 6" underground in the midwest seems likely to freeze) that does not seem wise. The check valve would hold water right up to the turn of the pipe. Either that, or switch to 2" pipe for that drain line (leaving 1-1/4" from the pump) if you are going to dig it all up anyway.

Comment: I dug into regrading the drain line last night. The thing looks like a roller coaster, complete with dives and a kink where it was run over a brick. Needless to say, I am pleased with the way it looks and will be finding a way to get it taken care of.